# WebView - No connection and content fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I want to show normal webview when is app connected to internet (actually thats what I have and want to add the second fragment), but when it's not connected to internet (It works, but it shows Webpage is not available, default android browser and I don't want it), I want to show another fragment with text view and button TRY AGAIN. Is there someone who can help me ? I am using SherlockFragment and below I am posting code with the Webview without the another fragment. Thanks for any answer.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        if (isOnline()){
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Prosím čakajte. Prebieha načítavanie...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                  if(progressDialog != null)
                      progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                      getActivity().setProgress(progress * 1000);
                      progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
                      if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                          progressDialog.dismiss();
                  }

      });

        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl("webpage");        
    }
        else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), class.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
        return v;
    }
    private boolean isOnline() {

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;

        } else {
        Log.v(getTag(), "Internet Connection Not Present");
        return false;
        }
    }
  }
```

LOG CAT

```
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at sk.soszm.polytechnicka.Novinky.isOnline(Novinky.java:71)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at sk.soszm.polytechnicka.Novinky.onCreateView(Novinky.java:31)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-08 09:17:57.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17630):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor whether the device is connected to the Internet or not. If it's not connected, just make the visibility of the `WebView` to `GONE` and display a text message.

Use this to check the Internet connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Once you've got the connection status, do this:

```
if(isConnected) {
  //your WebView code
} else {
  //TextView showing "Try Again"
}
```

You can use `setVisibility(int)` to programmatically show/hide a view

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

Comment: Thanks for respond, I tried to implements to my code, but it doesn't work. Can u please check the code which I edited please? Thanks. Also posting LogCat

Comment: @user2900523 What is line 71?

Comment: @user2900523 BTW, have you given the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Permissions I have
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> `

and line 71 is ` private boolean isOnline() { `